# DbUp for sqlserver creates schemas under dbo authorization for non dbo user

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-core, dbup

I'm trying to understand the underlying reason as to why DbUp upgrade creates schemas under dbo authorization, when the login/user in the connection string is neither an "owner", nor has "db_owner" role assigned.

To elaborate, let's say I manually create the following using the sa account:

- Server login **MyTestUser**, which has only one server role - public.
- Database **MyTest**.
- Database user **MyTestUser**, which maps to the **MyTestUser** login, who initially owns no schemas and contains the following database roles: db_backupoperator, db_datareader, db_datawriter, db_ddladmin

Now, let's say I have the initial script where I create a schema:

```
DECLARE @User NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @User = (SELECT CURRENT_USER)

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)    
SET @Sql = 'CREATE SCHEMA [MyTestSchema] AUTHORIZATION ' + @User;
EXEC(@Sql)
```

If I login to the database using **MyTestUser**, and execute the SQL directly on the database, I get the desired result where the owner of the new schema is **MyTestUser**.

Now, whenever I run an upgrade using DbUp for SQL Server (the **MyTestUser** is specified in the connection string), the same schema is created under **dbo** - which is not what I want. This also happens for the initial schema that the DbUp creates for a fresh database. I'm using **dbup-sqlserver 4.6.0** nuget.

The code to execute upgrade:

```
var upgradeEngine = DeployChanges.To
                    .SqlDatabase(databaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString, databaseSettings.Value.DefaultSchema)
                    .JournalToSqlTable(databaseSettings.Value.DefaultSchema, "SchemaVersions")
                    .WithScriptsFromFileSystem(scriptsPath)
                    .LogTo(upgradeLog)
                    .Build();

var result = upgradeEngine.PerformUpgrade();
```

And just for clarity, here's the connection string:

> data source=localhost\sqlexpress;initial catalog=MyTest;User
> ID=MyTestUser;Password=SuperSecret;integrated
> security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False

I'm struggling to understand as to why there's a difference in the two processes, maybe someone could shed some light?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't support schemas, a lot of products don't

Comment: In this case, you can look at the source code. I made a quick lookup for `dbo` and I find [this](https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp/blob/master/src/dbup-sqlserver/Helpers/TemporarySqlDatabase.cs#L53) on the source code, maybe the author assumes the `dbo` scheme on its process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this behaviour was due to my own unawareness of the connection string content. By setting *integrated security=True* I was telling the upgrader to use my windows credentials, thus ignoring the credentials specified in the connection string. Once I set that to false, eveything fell in order.